# Babel does not appear to be transforming my React-Native code

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I'm fairly new to RN and want to get flow types and decorators working in this project.

I am on version `0.41.2` of RN. It comes with a `.babelrc` in the project root, which I have added the plugins to:

```
{
"presets": ["react-native"],
"plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-flow-strip-types"]
}
```

I understand in older versions of RN I needed to extend the `.babelrc` from my `node_modules` folder, but that this shouldn't be the case on my current version.

So what gives, why can I not run my project without getting syntax errors?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: @loganfsmyth There are no errors, it fails silently. The syntax errors are to do with the flow types not being stripped out and the decorator `@` symbol not being transpiled

Answer (score 0):

Your config should work. Have you tried running `watchman watch-del-all` and `npm run start -- --reset-cache`/`yarn start -- --reset-cache`? If you update your `.babelrc` and meet errors this may help in some cases.